# How to add custom attribute for element using vue directives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have custom attribute `my-custom-attribute` which contains the id for the element I need to add and remove this attribute depending on the boolean.

I already tried this code and it is working fine, is there any way to make it using vuejs directives?
HTML:

```html
<div my-custom-attribute="my_element">
...
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("some_id");
if(my_bool) {
   el.setAttribute("my-custom-attribute", "#my-element");
} else {
   el.removeAttribute("my-custom-attribute")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a `directive` as global using the below example, it provides you three lifecycle hooks for you to control the behavior, read the following and try to implement. Let us know if any problem occurs with your implementation and start a separate thread

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

```
Vue.directive('my-custom-directive', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function (el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})
```